# How list States of a Country in ODOO v8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to list all the states of a country. 
In OpenERP v7, I suppose that could be work:

`_columns = {
    'country_id': fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country'),
    'state_id': fields.related('country_id', 'state_id', type="many2one", relation="res.country.state", string="State"),
}`

How can I do that in Odoo-v8?
I tried:

`country_id = fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country')
    state_id = fields.related('country_id', 'state_id', type="many2one", relation="res.country.state", string="State")`

But I got,`in 'module' is not defined 'related'`

the official documentation about relational fields is not very clear.

I think maybe I need a onchange method:

`@api.onchange('country_id')
 def: _onchange_country(self):
      #I don’t how list the states, inside this method`

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Odoo 8.0 new API  the field itself use the **related attribute** in any fields.
hear there have no any facility to add the separate field as related

Just like this..

```
country_id = fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country') 
state_id=fields.many2one(related='country_id.state_id.id', store=True)
```

I hope this should helpful for you .. :)

Comment: Thank for your answer! It worked as expected...And if a want to relate the tables: **res_country** whit **my_stated** how can I do it? In **my_state** I've the **id_parent** to related a country..

Comment: I can not understand your question please clarify me in depth

Comment: I builded a new class called **my_states** his attributes are `country_id` and `name`,so  when I tried to list his records I got an error, I supposed something is wrong with my class because it isn't part to `base` module...I don't now what I do now :( I would like to write you inbox for more details if you dont care!